# JQuery Username Validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Does anyone have a working example of a username checker using jquery validation and jquery addmethod?

Something like this:

```
$("#register_form").validate({
    onkeyup:false,
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            usernameCheck: true    // remote check for duplicate username
        },
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("usernameCheck", function(username) {
    var isSuccess = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: "username_availability.php",
        data: "username=" + username,
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        success:
        function(msg) {
            isSuccess = parseInt(msg);
        }
    });
    return isSuccess;
},"");
```

I've been looking all over Google for days, and I've noticed a number of threads like this that go unanswered or unsolved with a high view count. So if someone could provide a link or a solution, I'm sure a lot of JQuery noobs would benefit and be glad. :)

> Hey guys, thanks a lot for all your
>   help. I managed to find what I was
>   looking for though.
>
> The "milk example"? Really? It exists?
>
> --Yes my son, it exists and it's awesome:
>   http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/

Comment: Post your username_availability.php

Comment: Do you have something right now that is not working?  Without using the validate plugin, it depends how advanced you want this feature.  Do you want server and client side validation or just server side? **PRO TIP:** just using client side validation is a bad idea.

Comment: Note that at the very least you will want to url-encode username before putting it in the data.

Comment: or if you are using the post method json encode it

Comment: @Talljoe Or he changes the code to: data: {username: username} and jQuery will do it's magic :)

Comment: lol guys I just want a basic working example, nothing fancy... like I've seen at least 30 threads similar to this one that went unanswered and I've asked around in a previous thread and on other forums and I've tried all the recommendations that they gave and that you guys have given and none work - if you can do it - you'll be the first page on Google to do so, and I'm sure you know the benefits of that...

Comment: @Yoshi, exactly.  That's one step further than "the least" though. ;)

Comment: See also **[JQuery Username Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732331/jquery-username-validation?rq=1)**

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the the success method isn't being called by the time you return.  You can change your code to be:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("usernameCheck", function(username) {
    var result = $.ajax({
        url: "username_availability.php",
        data: {username: username},
        async: false,
        type: "POST"
    }).responseText;
    return result === '1';
},"");
```

Comment: What are the values returned from your php? If they're not '1' and '0' then you'll need to modify the code. Maybe post the important bits.  This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdp3k/) shows that the above code can work, so look to see what's going on.  Use Fiddler, Firebug, or IE's dev tools to trace the request.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `remote` type instead of making up your own.

```
$("#register_form").validate({
    onkeyup:false,
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            remote:'username_availability.php'
        },
});
```

It will pass a parameter of `username=foo` to your `username_availability.php` page.  Return true or false from that page.